# Composite Primary Key for DynamoDB using AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a DynamoDB table like the following:

```py
ddb.Table(self, table, 
    partition_key=ddb.Attribute(name="account_id",
    type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING),
    sort_key=ddb.Attribute(
        name="skey",
        type=ddb.AttributeType.STRING
    )
)
```

Ant now I want to add another column/key to the partition key

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a misunderstanding here. DynamoDB has two kinds of Primary Keys that identify a datapoint:

- **Simple Primary Key**: Only a partition key
- **Composite Primary Key**: Partition + Sort Key

In your case you've set up a composite primary key, which you seem to want. Now you're trying to add more attributes to the partition key.

That's not going to work - both partition and sort key have a 1:1 mapping to a single attribute.

A common technique to set up something like this is to combine the values that make up the partition key in the same attribute like this:

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TENANT#00001#USER#00001 | ORDER#123 | `{"whatever": "you", "want": "here"}` |
| TENANT#00001#USER#00002 | ORDER#133 | `{"whatever": "you", "want": "here"}` |
| TENANT#00111#USER#00023 | ORDER#433 | `{"whatever": "you", "want": "here"}` |